# Required Column 'TransacionId' does not exist in the results. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

SOLVED

FOR ANYONE WITH THE SAME PROBLEM, I ADDED FOR THE STORED PROCEDURE TO ALSO SELECT THE COLUMN TRANSACTIONID AND IT WORKED.

I am getting an error saying that my column TransactionId does not exist in the results? I have checked all the names on the SQL table and also my Class Entity, but it still saying it?

I am wanting to pass my `TransactionId` to my stored procedure so it brings back some results. I have tested the Stored Procedure in SQL and it works fine.

This is my `cAuditTransactionsEntity`:

```
    [Table(Name = "Audit_Transactions")]
public class cAuditTransactionsEntity
{
    private string _TransactionId;
    private string _PolicyNumber;
    private string _Title;
    private string _Forename;
    private string _Surname;
    private string _PolicyType;
    private int _TransactionUserId;
    private DateTime _TransactionDate;
    private int _TransactionTypeId;
    private string _Insurer;
    private string _ClientPostDetails;
    private int _TransactionStatusId;

    [Column(DbType = "CHAR(32)", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string TransactionId
    {
        get { return _TransactionId; }
        set { _TransactionId = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "VARCHAR(50)")]
    public string PolicyNumber
    {
        get { return _PolicyNumber; }
        set { _PolicyNumber = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "VARCHAR(50)")]
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set { _Title = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "VARCHAR(50)")]
    public string Forename
    {
        get { return _Forename; }
        set { _Forename = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "VARCHAR(50)")]
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return _Surname; }
        set { _Surname = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "VARCHAR(50)")]
    public string PolicyType
    {
        get { return _PolicyType; }
        set { _PolicyType = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "INT")]
    public int TransactionUserId
    {
        get { return _TransactionUserId; }
        set { _TransactionUserId = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "DATETIME")]
    public DateTime TransactionDate
    {
        get { return _TransactionDate; }
        set { _TransactionDate = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "INT")]
    public int TransactionTypeId
    {
        get { return _TransactionTypeId; }
        set { _TransactionTypeId = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "VARCHAR(50)")]
    public string Insurer
    {
        get { return _Insurer; }
        set { _Insurer = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "VARCHAR(255)")]
    public string ClientPostDetails
    {
        get { return _ClientPostDetails; }
        set { _ClientPostDetails = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "INT")]
    public int TransactionStatusId
    {
        get { return _TransactionStatusId; }
        set { _TransactionStatusId = value; }
    }
}
```

I have look though this and there is not a difference in the names.

Here is my Stored Procedure:

```
        [Function(Name = "SP_AUDIT_TRANSACTION_GET_TRANSACTION_INFO", IsComposable = false)]
    public ISingleResult<cAuditTransactionsEntity> GetTransactionInfo(
       [Parameter(Name = "pTransactionId", DbType = "CHAR(32)")] string TransactionId)
    {
        IExecuteResult objResult = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()), TransactionId);

        ISingleResult<cAuditTransactionsEntity> objresults = (ISingleResult<cAuditTransactionsEntity>)objResult.ReturnValue;

        return objresults;
    }
```

And finally this is the code I have where I pass the transactionId to the Stored Procedure:

```
    cEvolve_SP sp = new cEvolve_SP(Properties.Settings.Default.AppConnectionString);
    cAuditTransactionsEntity _Transactions;

    public xamlNewAudit(string transactionid)
    {
       _Transactions = new cAuditTransactionsEntity();

        _Transactions.TransactionId = transactionid;

        sp.GetTransactionInfo(transactionid);

        _Transactions.PolicyType = lblPolicyNumber.ToString();

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The line I am getting this error on is this line in the Stored Procedure:

```
IExecuteResult objResult = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()), TransactionId);
```

Mainly the Last bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has solved this question by doing following

FOR ANYONE WITH THE SAME PROBLEM, I ADDED FOR THE STORED PROCEDURE TO ALSO SELECT THE COLUMN TRANSACTIONID AND IT WORKED.